# How can I add « » in my sentence?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Does anybody know how to add these marks **«** bla bla **»**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the T1 encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
<<blah blah>>
\end{document}
```

If your document is UTF-8 encoded, then also direct input works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
«blah blah»
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How is that working with `<<`? I would've thought you'd need a negative kerning between the two.  But obviously you don't.

Comment: @A.Ellett T1 encoded fonts define ligatures for `<<` and `>>` (similarly to `--` and `---`).

Comment: @egreg what if i use \usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}.Is there somelthing else i have to do ?Am i going to follow the same steps?

Comment: @johnjohn Use `<<` and `>>`; the code page doesn't have the guillemets. But switch to UTF-8 as soon as possible.

Comment: i use greek as language and i have problem with utf8.